# Reactjs. Cannot pass variable to class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I m totally new to React. I am trying to pass a variable 'name' to my class, but it is not getting assigned. These names comes from another file. I cannot see names of people on my buttons. 
Before my Card was just a simple function and it was working fine. But after converting it into a class, name is not working. Pls help!

**BEFORE (Working):**

```
const Card = ({name, email}) => {

return  (

        <div>
            <h2 className='f5'>{name}</h2>
            <p className='f6'>{email}</p>
        </div>

    </div>
);
}
```

**AFTER (Not Working):**

```
class Card extends Component { 
    constructor({props, name}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            isToggleOn: true,
            name: this.name
        };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
 }

handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
} 
render() {
    var { name } = this.state;
    return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            { this.state.isToggleOn ? name : 'OFF' }
        </button>
    );  
    }
} 

ReactDOM.render(
  <Card />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
export default Card;
```

Comment: names are coming from which file?

Comment: @AkshayAggarwal That other file:

import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

const CardList = ({users}) => {

 return (
  <div>
   {
    users.map((user, i) => {
     return <Card key={users[i].id} 
      id={users[i].id}
      name={users[i].name} 
      email={users[i].email}
      />      
    })
   }
  </div>
 );
}

export default CardList;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you should change this piece of code:

```
this.state = { 
    isToggleOn: true,
    name: this.name
};
```

to this:

```
this.state = {
    isToggleOn: true,
    name:       name || ''
};
```

as you want to use the value of parameter.

Second, I don't think this is a root component, so most probably you should use it inside other component, which means that this piece of code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Card />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

is redundant, so you will need to remove it from current file.

And last, when you will use the `Card` component in another component, you should give it `name` property, something like:

```
<Card name="Some String" />
```

Comment: I am getting: Unexpected use of 'name' no-restricted-globals

Comment: It works now! I forgot to pass name in constructor. Ty =)

Answer (score 0):

The variable name should be passed by the special parameter props.
All varaibles coming from outside the compnent are passed via props.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Card name="Some name"/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Then in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) { // NOTE that only props gets passed to to constructor
     super(props)
     this.state = { 
        isToggleOn: true,
        name: props.name
};
```

This way you can set the state values in constructor, having the variable from outside.

I recommend you strongly to check out the official tutorial: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: Now I am getting:
Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals

Comment: Your example uses an undefined `name` variable.

Comment: Updated the example @TedKhi